# downloading is not happening when we use Tidy API in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6.2

I have a article(in the form of web content which has particular structure & template) which is calling an ajax method for downloading the entire article. I am using Tidy API for downloading the Article. But when we click on the article the page keeps on reloading for some time and it is displaying "**This page isn’t working, www.xyz.com took too long to respond,HTTP ERROR 504"**.Not getting what might be the root cause for it.**And the same code is working for other pages as well**.Please help me to find the solution for this.Thanks

Comment: So you're doing *something* (TM) and it doesn't work. With that level of information, you'll have to try *something else* (TM). But seriously: Show code. Make it easy to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:
  *Tidy tidy = new Tidy();**is = new ByteArrayInputStream(articleHtml.getBytes());**org.w3c.dom.Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(is, null);* *ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();* *renderer.layout();*> *renderer.createPDF(outputStream);*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)